# How to get the path of an image stored in internal storage?

Tags: android, image

I want to get the path of the image from internal storage.

```
if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
    String whatsAppMessage = "This is the number plate of vehicle in which I am going to travel ";

    //You can read the image from external drove too
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("here I want the path of the image stored in internal storage");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsAppMessage);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You put the file there in your app, so your app must know the path. getFilesDir() gives you the path to your internal files dir, you extend that with the path you used to put the image file there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> For internal   `Environment.getDataDirectory()`
>
> For external   `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: They're asking about internal storage, not external.